# CSS Clear depending on odd of even amount of items

Tags: html, css

I am laying out multiple tables in a page and I am wondering if it would be possible, using CSS only, to change the layout according to the total amount of tables. The overall conditions would be to always have a minimum of 2 tables side by side and a maximum of 3 tables wide. So clearing after every 3rd child for odd numbers and clearing after every 2nd child for even numbers. Is this doable?

Example with 4 tables:

OO

OO

Example with 5 tables:

OOO

OO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although CSS can't directly determine the number of children an element has, you can do some fun stuff with the sibling selector that should accommodate your needs:

```
.table:first-child:nth-last-child(4) + .table + .table {
    clear: both;
}

.table:first-child:nth-last-child(5) + .table + .table + .table {
    clear: both;
}
```

*Note: I'm just using a `div` with `class="table"` for brevity. Theoretically, this could apply to any selector.*

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74tc4ojL/)